# httpd service won't work after port change on centOS 6

Tags: linux, apache, nginx, centos, httpd.conf

I want to change Apache's port so I can use NGINx as a reverse proxy listening to port 80.

I changed the `Listen 0.0.0.0:80` and `Listen [::]:80` lines in the /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file to `Listen 0.0.0.0:8090` and `Listen [::]:8090` and when I run `sudo service httpd restart` and then `sudo service httpd status` it says:

```
Looking up localhost
Making HTTP connection to localhost
Alert!: Unable to connect to remote host.

lynx: Can't access startfile http://localhost/whm-server-status
```

what else do I need to change in the httpd.conf file?

My NGINx conf file is

```
server{
        listen 80;
        server_name mywebpage.com;
        #access_log off;
        #error_log off;
        #large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;

#this one is for the node app 
        location / {
                proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
                proxy_set_header Connection "";
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

#this one is for the apache one
        location /otherlocation {
                proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
                proxy_set_header Connection "";
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8090;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

}
```

which works perfectly when I serve my node app but if I change Apache's port it won't work

**EDIT:**
I also changed every `<VirtualHost *:8090>` and now it says

```
[Tue Feb 14 01:03:50 2017] [warn] VirtualHost 162.214.21.28:8090 overlaps with VirtualHost 162.214.21.28:8090, the first has precedence, perhaps you need a NameVirtualHost directive
[Tue Feb 14 01:03:50 2017] [warn] VirtualHost 162.214.21.28:8090 overlaps with VirtualHost 162.214.21.28:8090, the first has precedence, perhaps you need a NameVirtualHost directive
[Tue Feb 14 01:03:50 2017] [error] VirtualHost *:8090 -- mixing * ports and non-* ports with a NameVirtualHost address is not supported, proceeding with undefined results
[Tue Feb 14 01:03:50 2017] [warn] VirtualHost 162.214.21.28:8090 overlaps with VirtualHost 162.214.21.28:8090, the first has precedence, perhaps you need a NameVirtualHost directive
[Tue Feb 14 01:03:50 2017] [warn] NameVirtualHost 162.214.21.28:80 has no VirtualHosts
[Tue Feb 14 01:03:50 2017] [warn] NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80 has no VirtualHosts
```

Comment: `sudo service httpd stop` works?

Comment: does this fixed your problem `ipcs -s | grep nobody | perl -e 'while () { @a=split(/s+/); print \`ipcrm sem $a[1]\`}'`

Comment: @TRiNE yes, I can stop the service, if I do it once it doesn't say anything, but if I run it twice it says 'httpd (no pid file) not running'. Can you explain what that does?

Comment: @TRiNE it doesn't fix it. It just stays hanged saying `usage: ipcrm [ [-q msqid] [-m shmid] [-s semid]
          [-Q msgkey] [-M shmkey] [-S semkey] ... ]
deprecated usage: ipcrm {shm | msg | sem} id ...`

Comment: then, have you looked in httpd logs for startup errors?

Comment: @TRiNE where do I look them?? `/etc/httpd/logs/error_log` ?

Comment: if so, I looked at them and it says a lot , but the warnings [warn] and error [error] are the ones that I posted in the edit

Comment: Can you find `NameVirtualHost *:80` in `httpd.conf` ? Change it to `NameVirtualHost *:8090`

Comment: @TRiNE I can see it but it is between these comments `# DO NOT EDIT. AUTOMATICALLY GENERATED.  IF YOU NEED TO MAKE A CHANGE PLEASE USE THE INCLUDE FILES.` and just above are three includes, 2 are empties (pre_virtualhost_1.conf and pre_virtualhost_2.conf) and the other account_suspensions.conf just says `RewriteEngine On`

Comment: Also, there are 3 NameVirtualHost: `NameVirtualHost my.Dedicated.Ip:80` , `NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80` and `NameVirtualHost *`

Comment: Try this first, change `NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80` to `NameVirtualHost *:8090`

Comment: @TRiNE it gives me a new error `[error] VirtualHost *:8090 -- mixing * ports and non-* ports with a NameVirtualHost address is not supported, proceeding with undefined results`

Comment: Comment other `NameVirtualHost`s

Comment: @TRiNE ok, now it says `[warn] VirtualHost 162.214.21.28:8090 overlaps with VirtualHost 162.214.21.28:8090, the first has precedence, perhaps you need a NameVirtualHost directive` twice

Comment: what shows for `sudo service httpd start` now?

Comment: @TRiNE that warning twice, and when I do `sudo service httpd status` it says it was unable to connect to remote host

Comment: it seems beyond i cannot help you. will have to revert all things back to get work on port 80. then follow https://www.ostechnix.com/how-to-change-apache-ftp-and-ssh-default-port-to-a-custom-port-part-1/

Comment: @TRiNE thanks for trying and for the link!